# Am I doing right this variable substitution in this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I have this differential equation: $2x(1+\sqrt{x^2-y})dx - \sqrt{x^2 - y}dy = 0$. I'm trying to switch from $(x,y)$ to $(x,u=\sqrt{x^2-y})$. So let $u = \sqrt{x^2 - y}$. Then $y = x^2 - u^2$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 2x - 2u\dfrac{du}{dx}$ and $dy = 2xdx - 2udu$. But I'm not sure if I'm doing this substitution right. If it is right, then the equation gets solved pretty easily after this but the fact that $u$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ confuses me.

Comment: I see you have a great answer. As to your specific question about whether your expression for $du$ is right: Yes but you got there the wrong way. In the multivariate case, for $z=f(x,y)$, $dz = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\, dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \, dy$. The difference is subtle, but it is not correct to say that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is equal to $dy$ divided by $dx$.

Comment: @Chessnerd321 thanks, I had a feeling that I wasn't using the notation right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2x(1+\sqrt{x^2-y})dx - \sqrt{x^2 - y}dy = 0$$
$$(1+\sqrt{x^2-y})dx^2 - \sqrt{x^2 - y}dy = 0$$
$$dx^2+\sqrt{x^2-y})d(x^2 - y) = 0$$
$$dx^2+\sqrt{u}du = 0$$
I used $u=x^2-y$ but your substitution works fine too. The DE is separable. Integrate. Your substitution and calculation looks good. For $u=\sqrt {x^2-y}$
$$2xdx+\sqrt{x^2-y})d(x^2 - y) = 0$$
$$2xdx+udu^2 = 0$$
Note that $du^2=2udu$:
$$2xdx+2u^2du = 0$$
$$xdx+u^2du = 0$$
Integrate.